# How do I create a cache context in Drupal 8 that varies on user/node field data?

Tags: 8, caching

Let's say I have a complex render array that has two variations that depend on a simple if: whether the logged in user can edit a node inside it. There are two scenarios I look for:

1. The node was created by the logged in user, or:
2. The node's field_group (entity reference) matches the logged in user's field_group.

These two conditions are independent of roles/permissions so I can't fall back on those contexts. Originally, I simply used the "user" context but this would create far too much variation and potentially lead to a very large database table (not to mention it was inefficient to have to cache this again for every user).

I imagine I would need to create a context like: "caneditnode:nid" and somehow pass nid to a handler that would load the Node to check its fields and owner and compare to the data in Drupal::currentUser(). Is that possible? How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: I would check is the user is authehticated. You don't have to worry about the "potentially lead to a very large database table". There is already a ***load of data so concerning yourself with this is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a cache key for the two scenarios

```
$build['#cache']['keys'][] = $canedit ? 'caneditnode' : 'cannoteditnode';
```

and build the complex render array in a #pre_render callback. See https://dev.acquia.com/blog/drupal-8-performance-render-caching

Comment: :facepalm: I didn't realize I could use keys this way! Thank you! Drupal is awesome~

Comment: There are a number of limitiations with this. Where exactly are you adding this? Are you adding something to the node with hook_node_view() or a similar function or is this your own render array?

Answer (score 8):

A cache key is not the right solution as `dynamic_page_cache` won't vary on the right things.

What you do is:

You create a custom cache context (see `core.services.yml` for many examples), which itself is dependent on the [route] and [user] cache context (as it needs to check the node).

e.g. `cookies:[cookie_name]` is a good example. (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21Context%21CookiesCacheContext.php/class/CookiesCacheContext)

In that way you can have indeed a:

`caneditnode:[entity_id]`

Whenever this cache context is used, your handler is checked and needs to return the right information based on the given Context.

If `caneditnode` is given as cache context without context it could just throw an Exception or fallback to ['user', 'route'] as that is what it depends on.

In `getCacheableMetadata` you would just return the node cacheable metadata and the user.roles.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/cache_context.user.permissions for an example of a cache context, which itself depends on other data, which can be invalidated.