# Invalidate Internal Page Cache at certain times in a day for anonymous users

Tags: 8, caching

Let say I have a webshop open from 9am to 11am (data coming from config).
When the shop is closed, I would like to display a message (shop closed) and when the shop is open, my commerce product should be available. (only for 'lunch' bundle)

I have tried to update the following code: https://cornel.co/article/drupal8/page-cache-cookies-or-anything-available-http-request

Here is my try (edited with a comment from 4k4:

```
protected function getCacheId(Request $request)
{
    if (! isset($this->cid)) {
        $cid_parts = [
            $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . $request->getRequestUri(),
            $request->getRequestFormat(NULL)
        ];
        // Only cache by State of Store for some path
        if (strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/lunches/') != false) {
            $store_state = get_store_state(); 
            $cid_parts[] = $store_state['context']; //return a string like 'open' or 'close:9:30:11:00' if closed (like before 9:30 am or after 11:00am)
        }
        $this->cid = implode(':', $cid_parts);
    }
    return $this->cid;
}
```

As stated by 4k4, I must create a new context which will bubble up and will invalidate the Internal Cache page.

Here is the code of

```
class StateStoreCacheContext implements CacheContextInterface
```

stored in `mymodule/src/CacheContext/StateStoreCacheContext.php`

```
public function getContext()
{
    $storeState=get_store_state();
    return $storeState['context']; //return a string like 'open' or 'close:9:30:11:00' if closed (like before 9:30 am or after 11:00am)
}
```

And here is mys service declaration:

```
services:
   cache_context.state_store_context:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\CacheContext\StateStoreCacheContext
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: cache.context }
```

And here is the way I add my context to my page (in `mythem_preprocess_node(&$vars)`)

```
$vars['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'state_store_context';
```

Unfortunately, my page cache is not invalidate for anonymous users (but it is ok for logged-in users)

Comment: Is this really about invalidating the whole page cache or is it more about displaying a certain message at certain times?

Comment: The cache context doesn't exist, you have to create a custom one and add it to the node, a preprocess hook is OK for this. BTW you can't rely on the route name being present in the middleware, it's only there when storing the cache item but not when retrieving it. So better use the path to check the node type.

Comment: @leymannx: it is about invalidating the whole cache page

Comment: @4k4 I have 2 issues regarding creating a context: 1-I will have to implement `get_context()` with exactly the same logic as in `getCacheId()` (see upper)=>looks weird 2-My idea is to keep the internal page cache module, I have read somewhere else that it doesn't deal with context. Thank you for the route not being present, I will update the code

Comment: Yes, a custom cache context with exactly the same logic. You need the cache context for all other caches in Drupal like the entity render cache and the dynamic page cache and if you add the context to the node it will bubble up to all cache levels. With one exception, the Internal Page Cache, for which you are trying to find a solution in getCacheId().

Comment: @4k4 I get it: Contexts are for dynamic caching. I would like to focus my question only for anonymous user and internal page cache: how to invalidate this page cache when the store is closed or opened?

Comment: But the internal page cache for anonymous users gets the result from the dynamic cache and you need to make sure this delivers the correct result by adding the cache context. BTW invalidating is the wrong term here, you vary the cache id by a context and you have to do this in two places because one of the caches doesn't understand the standard Drupal way to do this (and wouldn't be able to run most contexts, because it is too early in the bootstrap process).

Comment: I've tried similar solutions, and finally switched over to adding custom cache tags, and invalidating those cache tags by cron. E.g. I added a `$variables['#cache']['tags'][] = 'MIDNIGHT';` in preprocess and invalidated it with a corresponding `\Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::invalidateTags(array('MIDNIGHT'));` in the `hook_cron` of the same module

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a cache context as well. See both answers in this topic:

[How do I create a cache context in Drupal 8 that varies on user/node field data?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241955/how-do-i-create-a-cache-context-in-drupal-8-that-varies-on-user-node-field-data)

You add a variation to the CID of the Internal Page Cache and a custom cache context to the node, so that it can bubble up to all elements which are dynamically cached. The difference is, CIDs can't bubble up, contexts can, and so vary all render elements no matter how deep they are nested.

Comment: I have tried what you say (also tried to add a cache key as described in your link) but unfortunately, this is not working for anonymous. I have updated my question with all your comments.

Comment: What do you mean by not working. Did you check the database for the cache items, whether they vary by the cache keys/contexts you've added? Or the result in the browser? This is not so easy to debug because the browser caches anonymous requests, too. For debugging (and production as well) you have to adjust the browser and proxy cache max-age: /admin/config/development/performance